# Extracting portions of low-dimensional numpy array into final axes of higher-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a static shape-`(l,l)` array `C`. I want to extract portions of it into some other array `K`, which has shape `(m,m,n,n)`. The starting index of what I want to extract from `C` is given in array `i0`, which has shape `(m,m)`.

Some element of `K` will be given by `K[i,j,:,:] = C[i0[i,j]:i0[i,j]+n, i0[i,j]:i0[i,j]+n]`. So going off some other similar questions it seemed like this might do the job...

```
C[i0[None, None, ...] + np.arange(n)[..., None, None], 
  i0[None, None, ...] + np.arange(n)[..., None, None], I, J]
```

which raises an `IndexError`. I guess this is because `C` is only 2D, and the dimensions can't be increased. Though that could be easily fixed by tiling `C`, since `C` is large, that would be rather expensive to remake `m*m` times.

So my question is how to extract different (2D) portions of a 2D array into corresponding portions of a 4D array.

Comment: you're correct, edited to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be with [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to create `2D` indexing meshes corresponding to the window of `(n,n)` shape, adding those with `i0` that's extended with two new axes along which broadcasting would take place. Finally, we simply index into `C` to give us the desired `4D` output. Thus, one implementation would be like so -

```
N = np.arange(n)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(N,N)
out = C[i0[...,None,None] + Y,i0[...,None,None] + X]
```

Sample run -

```
In [153]: C
Out[153]: 
array([[3, 5, 1, 6, 3, 5, 8, 7, 0, 2],
       [8, 4, 6, 8, 7, 2, 6, 2, 5, 0],
       [3, 7, 7, 7, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 6],
       [7, 0, 8, 2, 1, 1, 0, 4, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 5, 6, 8, 0, 0],
       [4, 6, 1, 0, 5, 6, 2, 1, 7, 4],
       [0, 5, 5, 3, 7, 5, 7, 1, 4, 0],
       [6, 4, 4, 7, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5],
       [5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 2, 5],
       [3, 7, 1, 0, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]])

In [154]: i0
Out[154]: 
array([[1, 0, 4, 4],
       [0, 4, 4, 0],
       [2, 3, 1, 3],
       [2, 2, 0, 4]])

In [155]: n = 3

In [157]: out[0,0,:,:]
Out[157]: 
array([[4, 6, 8],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [0, 8, 2]])

In [158]: C[i0[0,0]:i0[0,0]+n,i0[0,0]:i0[0,0]+n]
Out[158]: 
array([[4, 6, 8],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [0, 8, 2]])
```